# jQuery .show()/.hide() problems

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having a problem with my site. The idea is that theres a div with a image and text, and when you click it another div will slide down from the first div, with some more text and stuff. I use .slideToggle when you click the first div, and the second div slides up and down just as i want. But when i load the page, the second div are already "down" where i want it to be up as default. I have tried:

```
$('#second_div').hide();
$(document).on('click', 'div', function() {
    $(this).next().show();
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
});
```

(all in $(document).ready(function() {}); ofc)
but this only makes some of them hide, and when i click them they just roll down and up again immediately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
#second_div {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not show us your HTML and CSS, I can only assume how you want it to look like.

I created a working demo on JSFiddle while copying most of your JS: http://jsfiddle.net/2EL7q/

I recommend hiding the second div using CSS, not with JS. Also, you don't wanna call the `.show()` function if you want to invoke other animations to the element.

HTML:

```
<div id=first_div>Click me</div>
<div id=second_div>Second div</div>
```

CSS:

```
#second_div {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#first_div").click(function() {
        $("#second_div").slideToggle();
    });
});
```